# Changing between 2 images with a button

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS"/>
    <link href= "Task1.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
    <title> Task 1.1 HTML and CSS Demo Page</title>
    <script src="Task1.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Title of Article about Interesting Visualisation</h1>
    </header>
    <h2>Author of Interesting Article</h2>
    <p>The NAPLAN is a test that measures students’ <b>knowledge, skills, and abilities</b> over an extended amount of time. Instead, It examines students’ general understanding and advancement in literacy and numeracy rather than focusing on a specific subject. Studying NAPLAN <i>past papers</i> is one of the ways that you can ensure your child’s preparation for the NAPLAN.</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Knowledge</li>
        <li>Skills</li>
        <li>Abilities</li>
    </ol>
    <button type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="changeImage('2011')">2011</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="changeImage('2017')">2017</button>
    <figure>
        <img id="2011" src="images/NT_Naplan_Reading_Results_2011.png" alt="Naplan Results"/> 
            <figcaption>Fig 1. Percent of children above national minimum standard in reading in 2011 for Year 3, 5, 7 and 9 for Non-Indiginous and Indiginous children in the Nothern Teritory. Data Source: <a href="">NAPLANresults</a></figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
    <img id="2017" src="images/NT_Naplan_Reading_Results_2017.png" alt="Naplan Results"/>
        <figcaption>Fig 2. Percent of children above national minimum standard in reading in 2017 for Year 3, 5, 7 and 9 for Non-Indiginous and Indiginous children in the Nothern Teritory. Data Source: <a href="">NAPLANresults</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>The overall NAPLAN recipe for success is that the more I practiced for my Naplan testing and experienced success, the more confident I felt. It really helped on the day as I went into the test more relaxed and with a clear head space.</p>

<footer>
    <p><b>COS30045 Data Visualiastion</b></p>
    <p><b>27th February 2018</b></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function changeImage(imgid)
{
    if(imgid=='2011')
    {
        document.getElementById(imgid).src="images/NT_Naplan_Reading_Results_2017.png";
    }
    else if(imgid=='2017')
    {
        document.getElementById(imgid).src="images/NT_Naplan_Reading_Results_2011.png";
    }
}
```

This is my code so far, everything works but I can't figure out how to get my images to change. At the moment I have 2 images and I can get them to change to the other but I want 1 image that will change to either of the images I choose when clicking the button. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: check the `src` of the image instead of `id` and then change it to image source with the other one.

Comment: `but I want 1 image that will change to either of the images I choose when clicking the button` what does this mean?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I'm not sure what you mean by that. How will changing the source with the other one help?

Comment: @void I mean that at the moment there are 2 images. instead of 2 images i want 1 that when clicking the one of the buttons it will change the image to the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep one image with some `id`, then based on your argument change the `src` of the image like below. I have added the image `id` ad `testimg` and referring this one to toggle the image.

```
<button type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="changeImage('2011')">2011</button>
<button type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="changeImage('2017')">2017</button>
<figure>
    <img id="testimg" src="images/NT_Naplan_Reading_Results_2011.png" alt="Naplan Results"/> 
    <figcaption>Fig 1. Percent of children above national minimum standard in reading in 2011 for Year 3, 5, 7 and 9 for Non-Indiginous and Indiginous children in the Nothern Teritory. Data Source: <a href="">NAPLANresults</a></figcaption>
</figure>
```

**JS**

```
function changeImage(imgid)
{
   if(imgid=='2011') { document.getElementById("testimg").src="images/NT_Naplan_Reading_Results_2011.png";
   }
   else if(imgid=='2017') { document.getElementById("testimg").src="images/NT_Naplan_Reading_Results_2017.png";
   }
}
```

Comment: ah okay i got ya, thank you. Also do you know how i would change the figcaption as well so when the 2011 image is chosen then the fig 1 caption will show up under it and same with the 2017?

Comment: keep both the `figcaption` and hide the second one initially then based on your selection display it. check this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/7bgsrk9o/4/

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```js
    function changeImage(imgid)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("1");
    var y = document.getElementById("2");
    
    if (imgid=='2011') {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        y.style.display = "block";
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS"/>
    <link href= "Task1.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
    <title> Task 1.1 HTML and CSS Demo Page</title>
    <script src="Task1.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="changeImage('2011')">
    <header>
        <h1>Title of Article about Interesting Visualisation</h1>
    </header>
    <h2>Author of Interesting Article</h2>
    <p>The NAPLAN is a test that measures students’ <b>knowledge, skills, and abilities</b> over an extended amount of time. Instead, It examines students’ general understanding and advancement in literacy and numeracy rather than focusing on a specific subject. Studying NAPLAN <i>past papers</i> is one of the ways that you can ensure your child’s preparation for the NAPLAN.</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Knowledge</li>
        <li>Skills</li>
        <li>Abilities</li>
    </ol>
    <button type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="changeImage('2011')">2011</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="changeImage('2017')">2017</button>
    <figure id="1">
        <img id="2011" src="https://www.nature.com/polopoly_fs/7.44180.1495028629!/image/WEB_GettyImages-494098244.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_630/WEB_GettyImages-494098244.jpg" alt="Naplan Results"/> 
            <figcaption>Fig 1. Percent of children above national minimum standard in reading in 2011 for Year 3, 5, 7 and 9 for Non-Indiginous and Indiginous children in the Nothern Teritory. Data Source: <a href="">NAPLANresults</a></figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure id="2">
    <img id="2017" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/sunrise-on-yosemite-valley-picture-id505872990?k=6&m=505872990&s=612x612&w=0&h=XcdHhkC9PF9-saYT6n_GQD-0Hf8dbI_Q4wfYlZZGpNk=" alt="Naplan Results"/>
        <figcaption>Fig 2. Percent of children above national minimum standard in reading in 2017 for Year 3, 5, 7 and 9 for Non-Indiginous and Indiginous children in the Nothern Teritory. Data Source: <a href="">NAPLANresults</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>The overall NAPLAN recipe for success is that the more I practiced for my Naplan testing and experienced success, the more confident I felt. It really helped on the day as I went into the test more relaxed and with a clear head space.</p>

<footer>
    <p><b>COS30045 Data Visualiastion</b></p>
    <p><b>27th February 2018</b></p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```